# Nagios slack channel integration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, slack, channel, nagios

I'm using slack_nagios.pl script. Ubuntu 14.05 and Nagios 4.4.5 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tinyspeck/services-examples/master/nagios.pl
I have one channel working, but I need to send notifications to different channels. In my case: warnings have go to "it_warning" and critical alerts must go to "it_critical". I have created 2 set of slack notification commands as below, but I only receive the alerts always in one channel (warning). Is like slack is not able to differ between the 2 commands, despite in the *service_notification_options* section in the "slack" contact has w,r and in the "slack_critical" has c,r.

No error is received, tested separately the channels works ok.
Can you help help me or point me in the right direction?.

```
define contact {
   contact_name                     slack
   alias                            Slack
   service_notification_period      24x7
   host_notification_period         24x7
   service_notification_options     w,r
   host_notification_options        d,r
   service_notification_commands    notify-service-by-slack
   host_notification_commands       notify-host-by-slack
   }

define contact {
   contact_name                     slack_critical
   alias                            Slack_critical
   service_notification_period      24x7
   host_notification_period         24x7
   service_notification_options     c,r
   host_notification_options        d,r
   service_notification_commands    notify-service-critical-by-slack
   host_notification_commands       notify-host-critical-by-slack
   }

define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name       admins
    alias                   Nagios Administrators
    members                 slack,nagiosadmin,slack_critical
    }


define command {
   command_name     notify-service-by-slack
   command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-warnings -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field SERVICEDESC="$SERVICEDESC$" -field SERVICESTATE="$SERVICESTATE$$
   }

define command {
   command_name     notify-host-by-slack
   command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-warnings -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field HOSTSTATE="$HOSTSTATE$" -field HOSTOUTPUT="$HOSTOUTPUT$" -field$
   }

    define command {
   command_name     notify-service-critical-by-slack
   command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-critical -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field SERVICEDESC="$SERVICEDESC$" -field SERVICESTATE="$SERVICESTATE$$
   }

define command {
   command_name     notify-host-critical-by-slack
   command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-critical -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field HOSTSTATE="$HOSTSTATE$" -field HOSTOUTPUT="$HOSTOUTPUT$" -field$
   }
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not an acceptable problem description

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post with more data.

Comment: you should start by reading the nagios.log and look at what it's saying when you expect notifications to go out. it will tell you which command is being used. if you're only getting messages in `#it-warnings` it's probably because the "slack" contact or the underlying command is the only one being used.

Comment: Hello, i have publish the solution. Have a look if you feels like. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. here the steps to configure warnings alert to be send to a particular channel and critical alerts to another one.

You have to create 2 separate files with the contact, group and the commands as below, changing the channel, service_notification_options, service_notification_commands, host_notification_commands
Do not forget to add into the file you have defined the service the contact_groups (will be 2). Please give me some likes if you can. Thanks!

```
define contact {
  contact_name                             slack
  alias                                    Slack
  service_notification_period              24x7
  host_notification_period                 24x7
  service_notification_options             w,u,r
  host_notification_options                d,r
  service_notification_commands            notify-service-by-slack
  host_notification_commands               notify-host-by-slack 
  }

define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name       admins
    alias                   Nagios Administrators
    members                 nagiosadmin,slack
    }


define command {
  command_name     notify-service-by-slack
  command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-alerts-test -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field HOSTSTATE="$HOSTSTATE$" -field HOSTOUTPUT="$HOSTOUTPUT$" -field NOTIFICATIONTYPE="$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$"
  }

define command {
  command_name     notify-host-by-slack
  command_line     /usr/local/bin/slack_nagios.pl -field slack_channel=#it-alerts-test -field HOSTALIAS="$HOSTNAME$" -field HOSTSTATE="$HOSTSTATE$" -field HOSTOUTPUT="$HOSTOUTPUT$" -field NOTIFICATIONTYPE="$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$" 
  }


define service {
name                            generic-service  
retain_status_information       1                   
retain_nonstatus_information    1              
is_volatile                     0                      
check_period                    24x7                 
max_check_attempts              3                      
check_interval                  10                      
retry_interval                  2   
contact_groups                  admins,admins_critical  
notification_interval           60                     
notification_period             24x7
}
```